Как использовать BNO055 через HIT over i2c
Мы используем плату Arduino Nano и подключили к ней датчик Bno055 через HID over i2c (далее просто HIT). Для целей академического проекта нам нужно разобраться, как программировать датчик через этот интерфейс, а не через обычный i2c.
Информации об этом в интернете крайне мало. Самая популярная библиотека Adafrut для этого датчика, как я понял, не поддерживает HIT. Я не нашел ни одной библиотеки, которая поддерживает этот интерфейс. Также выяснилось, что стандартная библиотека Wire для i2c тоже не поддерживает HIT. Будем благодарны за любую помощь. Заранее большое спасибо.
